# Pthread, kill the thread has created by JNI

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface, pthreads

In our project, some of the codes are native, and invoked by JNI, so everything is looking good unless we decided to run some invokes parallel, but the issue(the unclear thing) is that either run the thread by Java or pthread?!

We prefer pthread because of its better management and power, but the question is.

suppose a native code starts a pthread, so we need to have the pthread reference in order to cancel/exit the thread with another method, so the first question is, how would I retunr the pthread id to the java code, is it possible, is pthread id is int?

```
native int start_thread();
```

the next question is, is it possible to pass a Java object(interface) to pthread instead of a native method? something like this

```
native int start_thread(pthread_start ref);//where pthread_start is a java interface with one method, like Runnable
```

and the last question, once we got the pthread reference, is it possible to just pass it to another native method to exit/cancel it?

```
native void kill_thread(int pthread_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the pointer to your pthread_t structure within Java, so long as you 'new' it in your native code.

With that pointer, you can call back into your native code for thread management(join, kill).

Likewise, when you are starting your thread, you can pass a reference to your Java object, which will arrive in the native code as a pointer.  While I don't recommend trying to call your Java function(i.e. Runnable ) directly from your pthread_create call, you can pass that Java object pointer to your native thread routine, which in turn can invoke your Java method via normal JNI calls.